# How to duplicate/clone an feature X times in FME?

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I want to clone two datasets in FME 2020. The number of copies shall be the number of features from the other dataset. The number of features from both input datasets changes every time.

So how can I put the number of features in a variable and use these within the cloner?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution by referring to takashi's post:

https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D54Q000080hIrOSAU/how-do-i-read-the-number-of-records-produced-from-a-transformer-and-use-that-number-in-a-cloner-transformer-not-directly-connected

[image]